# grab gold value using curl

Tags: php, curl

I am new to php curl, can you help me to write code for grabbing gold value from this page http://www.domain.com/gold.php

from following line i just want **27742.00**

```
Gold price today in India (Rs/10gm) is 27742.00 (-67)
```

Does it require HTML parser or just curl can do it alone?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex can do this for you.

```
preg_match('#Gold price today in India <b>\(Rs\/10gm\)</b> is <b>([0-9\.]+)#', file_get_contents('http://www.marketonmobile.com/gold_price_india.php'), $matches);
echo 'The price is: '.$matches[1];
```

Comment: This regex needs some work to ignore or parse the `<b>` tags in the text.

Comment: @Sjoerd Yeah, posted it before testing. The poster didn't include the <b> in his question.

Comment: good suggestion, yes we could use regex for this but somehow above code is not returning results.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the page with curl or [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). When you have the page, you can get the value with a HTML parser or a [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

Answer (score 0):

> Does it require HTML parser or just curl can do it alone?

cUrl alone can not parse HTML, so you need a HTML/Text parser that works on the return value of the cUrl request.

Example HTML parser with xpath:

```
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/gold.php';
$expr = 'string(//div[@class="gold"]/b[2]/text())';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$price = trim($xp->evaluate($expr));
```